# Ubuntu Automatically Logs out as the Software Center is opened

Tags: 13.04, software-center

I have a really weird problem ...

Once I open the software center, my machine (using ubuntu 13.04) logs out after ~ 8 sec ...

But if I minimized the software center, nothing happens ... After I maximize it, the counter starts again and after ~ 8 sec the machine logs out again ...

I noticed that minimizing resets the counter

Please help because its really annoying not to be able to install apps from the software center without minimizing it every 3~4 seconds

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling the software center?

Comment: yes I did that with no luck ... Still the same problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by removing 'swapspace'. For some unknown reason 'swapspace' was conflicting with ubuntu 13.04

Just type in:

```
sudo apt-get purge swapspace
```